# Julian date function unknown string date error

Tags: python, datetime, julian-date

Problem:

using Pandas `to_datetime()` function to cast to date, then using the `to_julian_date()` function for converting date to julian.

```
pd.to_datetime('date_of_last_service').to_julian_date()
```

format error as unknown string date error

Background:

working in python3, have these dates as example to convert to julian:

```
Data sample:

0       2017-10-02
1       2017-12-11
2       2017-12-13
3       2018-07-23
4       2018-08-24
5       2018-11-09


df['date_of_last_service'] = df[pd.to_datetime('date_of_last_service').to_julian_date()]
```

Comment: I don't understand the syntax you are using. You're not providing `to_datetime` a format string to go off, and you're trying to use it as some kind of mask on the whole dataframe.

Comment: df.dtypes. data_of_last_services is datetime64

Comment: I assigned to column in dataframe the converted julian date for the existing calendar date

Comment: If `date_of_last_service` is already a `datetime64` then why are you using `to_datetime` on it?

Comment: yes, I see, the to_datetime() is working on a datetime64 field, not a string. so perhaps I only need to_julian() on this datetime field

Comment: If it's a string, then you need to pass `format=` as a named argument to `to_datetime` so that it knows how to translate the string to a datetime64 value. If it's already a datetime, then there's no need to call `to_datetime` on it because it already is a datetime. Still, I think then applying it as a column reference is wonky

Comment: so the solution is to_julian(df['date_of_last_service']

Answer (score 0):

df['date_of_last_service'].dt.strftime('%y%j') solved date conversion to Julian data as well.